Gangster Television Show Identification
I can only remember a particular scene.
Three people were in a room, at least two black men and a woman. I can't recall her appearance. One of the men was smaller and had guns, and he was intimidating someone by pointing a gun at them sideways.  During this another man appears. He was really muscular with a tight white shirt and I believe wearing a gold chain necklace around his neck.
The woman calls him God, and the large man proceeds to break the smaller man's neck. 
I've been trying to remember this for years because it was a riveting scene while I was watching it but I could never find it again after I had to leave the house.
It could have been a movie, but I feel like it was a show. 
It was in English, and it was not about the mafia. I saw it on television sometime in the early 2000s. I want to say that "Dark Angel" and "Firestarter: Rekindled" were trailers/commercials I frequently saw on television while I was watching it.

When did you watched it? Approximative year? Languages ? Could be mafia ? If yes, Italian Mob, Yakuza, Irish Mob, etc. ?

I found it. The show is called Fastlane. The episode is called Offense (Part 2).
I went through all of the shows in 2002 and Googled "God" with the titles, and one guy wrote, "That fight scene between Deaq and God." 

The casting sounds ridiculous but the plot is actually intriguing. May have to hunt that one down...
